# Is Chip really an alcoholic?

Tags: character, analysis, flaked

In the first words of the series, Chip, the main character of the *[Flaked](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4973548/)* is on an AA meeting where he tells a story about his accident: he was drunk-driving and he has killed a man. He is very repentant of it but admits that now, for over 10 years, thanks to AA he is sober.

This always starts a "feel-good" sensation amongst the listeners and Chip is a well-liked person among the people of Venice, because people love a repent sinner.

But during the course of the series, we find that this is not exactly true: not only he has been drinking for the past 18 months, but also the accident story is a bit more complicated. His landlord calls him to his face as a "fake, who is scared of admitting the truth".

So my question is - is he really an alcoholic? We can see his friend from the AA "falling off the bandwagon" and the results are a spectacular mess. In contrast, as Chip says himself - no one has noticed him drinking, especially since he does it in small doses (a few sips of "kombucha", which is in fact his friend's wine) - something that is rather uncharacteristic for addicts, that usually drink until they are completely smashed (and also have a lowered tolerance for alcohol). Is the "repent alcoholic" story just a way to get attention?

Comment: I haven't seen the show, so I can't provide a definitive answer, but maybe Chip is a [functional alcoholic](https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/addiction/high-functioning-alcoholic)?

Comment: ["Chip isn't even an alcoholic, which is why we've seen him secretively sipping wine throughout the season. So Chip has been lying — but he's been doing it to protect people, not because he has issues."](https://www.vox.com/2016/3/13/11213538/flaked-review-netflix-will-arnett)

Comment: @BCdotWEB well, agian it is not so simple - Chip says that the accident WAS his fault because indeed he was drunk and just before the accident he has distracted the driver. He does sip his wine and later says that "maybe I am not alcoholic any more" (or was ever), then again later he admits to having serious issues with alcohol that has ruined his life. I am simply confused and the quoted article seems to be one-sided.